# How does splunk dashboard actually display the search query data?

Tags: splunk, splunk-dashboard

I am new to Splunk and have been exploring its features. I have uploaded some dummy data in CSV format and tried to create a dashboard out of it.
My query is if some new data is added, how does the dashboard reflect the change in data?

Any understanding of it is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To display new data the search that populates the dashboard must be re-run.  That can be automatic or manual.